# JAXB namespaces missing after marshalling

Tags: namespaces, jaxb, marshalling, default

I have generated Java classes from XSD and i want to marshal from JAXB Classes with the prefix namespace

here is what i have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/event"  
        xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/event"  
        elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
<element name="Events" type="tns:EventsType"></element>  
<complexType name="EventsType">  
<sequence>  
<element name="Event" type="tns:inputFlowEventType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"></element>  
</sequence></complexType>  
<complexType name="inputFlowEventType">  
<sequence>  
<element name="DISTRIBUTOR_ID" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">  
<simpleType><restriction base="string"><maxLength value="17"></maxLength></restriction></simpleType>  
</element>  
</sequence>  
</complexType>  
</schema>
```

and i have this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>  <Events xmlns="http://www.example.org/event"><Event><DISTRIBUTOR_ID>6</DISTRIBUTOR_ID></Event></Events>
```

instead of this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>  <tns:Events xmlns="http://www.example.org/event">    <tns:Event><tns:DISTRIBUTOR_ID>6</tns:DISTRIBUTOR_ID></tns:Event></tns:Events>
```

can someone knows what is wrong ?

thanks

Comment: First of all, you have a typo in the last section you should be expecting rather (note the xmlns:tns=''..' section):

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
     <tns:Events xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/event">
        <tns:Event><tns:DISTRIBUTOR_ID>6</tns:DISTRIBUTOR_ID></tns:Event>
      </tns:Events>

Answer (score 0):

The two documents are equivalent in terms of their namespace qualification.  The first specifies a default namespace and the second declares a names with a prefix.  If you would like to control the prefix that is used the answer will depend upon the JAXB implementation you are using.  MOXy will use the prefixes declared inside the @XmlSchema annotation. The JAXB RI has a NamespacePrefixMapper extension (also supported by MOXy):

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html